# How to test Http Pool in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, mockery

I have this class that push data to multiple urls using [Http::Pool](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#concurrent-requests).

```
class Pusher()
{
    public function __construct($data, $headers)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->headers = $headers;
    }

    public function pushToAddresses()
    {
        $addresses = get_address_somewhere_here();

        $responses = Http::pool(fn (Pool $pool) => $addresses->map(fn ($address) => $this->pushData($pool, $address)));
    }


    public function pushData(Pool $pool, $address)
    {
        return $pool->withHeaders($this->headers)
            ->withBody($this->data, 'application/json')
            ->post($address->url);
    }
}
```

Question: how do I mock the `Pool` so I can test that `withHeaders`, `withBody`, `post` are called correctly with the correct data?

Something like:

```
$mockPool = \Mockery::mock(Pool::class);
$mockPool->shouldReceive('withHeaders')->once()->with(['header1', 'header2']);
$mockPool->shouldReceive('withBody')->once()->with('{body here...}', 'application/json');
$mockPool->shouldReceive('post')->once()->with('address url here...');
```

Comment: Http::Pool is from the Laravel base library, you don't need to test it. It falls in the responsibility of the library to test it, you just use it and can expect it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with Guzzle mocking (Laravels http is a guzzle wrapper), is it is easier to create stub responses, then to mock it. `Laravel` has a method for this, otherwise see the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#faking-responses). You won't secure input is correct, but this is the pragmatic approach.

```
Http::fake([
    'address/url/1' => Http::response(['your response' => 'data'], 201, ['Headers']),
    'address/url/2' => Http::response(['your response' => 'data'], 201, ['Headers']),
]);
```

In general mocking never really tests it works as your mocking is your defined functionality and not the api's. Which our lord and savior famously stated. I do not totally agree with it, i mostly mock out of convenience for test execution.

[image: Taylor ortwell tweet]